# prevent asking "Missing JSDoc comment" for standard react methods in typescript project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, tsdoc

we have React project with Typescript.
We use **TSDoc** to standardize the doc comments used in TypeScript code

Our eslint.trc file as follow:

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "google",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:prettier/recommended"
    ],
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": 12,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin",
        "eslint-plugin-tsdoc"
    ],
    "settings": {
        "react": {
            "version": "detect"
        }
    },
    "rules": {
        "tsdoc/syntax": "warn",
        "valid-jsdoc" : 0,
        "@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types": "off"
    }
}
```

How to configure this configuration file, for not asking ESLINT about documenting standard react methods, like `constructor(),static getDerivedStateFromProps(),render(),componentDidMount() and etc.`

We can switch `"require-jsdoc":"off"`, but it also will not ask out user defined methods in class.

Comment: FWIW: It's "standard" (with  "d" at the end, not a "t").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've resolved this problem with this plugin
https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-require-jsdoc-except?activeTab=readme

You can add your function names at ignore:

```
 "ignore":[
            "constructor", "render","componentDidUpdate","getDerivedStateFromProps","componentDidMount"
         ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `.eslintrc.js` rules:

```
rules: {
  'require-jsdoc': [
    'error',
    {
      require: {
        FunctionDeclaration: false,
        MethodDefinition: false,
        ClassDeclaration: false,
        ArrowFunctionExpression: false,
        FunctionExpression: false,
      },
    },
  ],
},
```

Read more:
https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/require-jsdoc